# How can I restrict a git command with specific options?

Tags: bash, git

The reason might be silly but I have a very bad habit of using `git commit -am` and I hate it. I know I can revert that but I was wondering if there is a way that I can prevent the command from executing at all?

For example, is there a way I add a script or alias to my .bashrc so that every time I run `git commit -am "message"` it prevents it from running and shows me some message?

Edit:
As @chepner mentioned in the comments, I should be more clear, the part I don't like is the `-a`.

Comment: What about it do you hate? The resulting small commit message?

Comment: @chepner I prefer to think about adding each file to the commit separately.

Comment: Just write a `git.sh` script to pre-check the options (don't allow `-a`), then put `alias git=/path/to/git.sh` in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: So it's the `-a` you want to prevent?

Comment: @chepner Yes, exactly...........

Comment: There's no way to specifically disable the `-a` option. You can write a wrapper that tries to parse the command line and exit if `-a` is detected, as Jack suggests, but doing that is trickier than it sounds. You don't just have `-a` in isolation; it can be part of of a longer string of combined options (e.g., `git commit -paz`), and you also have to check for `--all`, its long-option synonym.

Comment: @chepner actually the complications you just mentioned are the reason I ended up asking the question here. I thought there might be an easier way to do this. I probably might just write a wrapper which handle a s few cases I use mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you *can* write a *pre-commit hook* that checks for this.  It's not perfect, by any means, because it checks for too much: any `git commit --include somefile` will trigger it as well.

Here is a sample (and not useful) pre-commit hook that uses this technique.  It should be obvious how to adapt it for your desires.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
path=$(basename $GIT_INDEX_FILE)
case $path in
index) echo "normal commit";;
index.lock) echo "commit -i or -a";;
next-index-*.lock) echo "commit -o";;
*) echo "something else: $GIT_INDEX_FILE";;
esac
exit 1
```

(Make this executable and place it in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.)